# ¿Cómo valido la cantidad de números enteros y decimales máximos en un número?

Tags: javascript, regex

He estoy intentando validar mediante una expresión regular que un número tenga ciertos números enteros y números decimales pero no logro que me lo valide.

Quiero que solo pueda tener como máximo 3 números enteros y 5 decimales como máximo.

Tengo esto:

```
var numero = 22.222222;
var exp = /^[0-9]{3}+(,[0-9]{5}+)?$/;

if(exp.test(numero)){
    console.log("correcto");
}else{
    console.log("error");
}
```

Ese numero me debería dar error porque supera los 5 decimales.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para indicar "como mucho X caracteres" debes decir `{1,X}`.

Por tanto, la expresión debe ser del tipo:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{1,5})$
```

Velo en acción:

```js
var re = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{1,5})$");

var numero = "22,222222";

if (re.test(numero)) {
    console.log("correcto");
} else {
    console.log("error");
}

var numero = "22,2222";

if (re.test(numero)) {
    console.log("correcto");
} else {
    console.log("error");
}
```

Nótese también que tus cuantificadores `+` no hacían ningún función, por lo que los eliminé.

> A esa expresión regular que le debo poner para que la parte decimal pueda ser opcional?

Para que algo sea opcional debes añadirle un `?` final después del bloque.

En tu caso:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{1,5})?$
//         ^           ^^
```

```js
var re = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{1,5})?$");

var numero = "22";

if (re.test(numero)) {
    console.log("correcto");
} else {
    console.log("error");
}
```

Comment: Me ha sido útil tu respuesta @fedorqui. Ahora te pregunto, a esa expresión regular que le debo poner para que la parte decimal pueda ser opcional?

Comment: @MarioGuiber acabo de actualizar mostrando cómo.

Comment: Perfecto @fedorqui, gracias por el aporte.